# Why did my pipenv disappear after python upgrade?

Tags: django, pip

I had an existing project an everything was fine. As Heroku seemed to need a specific python runtime version for deployment, i upgraded python (windows 64) to 3.7.4
When running pipenv shell in my usual folder, i have this message :

```
C:\Users\henry\Desktop\testldc>pipenv shell
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: C:\Users\henry\Desktop\testldc\Pipfile
Using c:\users\henry\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe 
(3.7.4) to create virtualenv…
[=== ] Creating virtual environment...
```

and then i get this error :

```
Creating virtual environment...
Failed creating virtual environment
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File 
"c:\users\henry\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 254, in install
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       
editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File 
"c:\users\henry\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1741, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       
pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File 
"c:\users\henry\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\pipenv\core.py", line 574, in ensure_project
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       
pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File 
"c:\users\henry\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\pipenv\core.py", line 506, in ensure_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       python=python, 
site_packages=site_packages, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File 
"c:\users\henry\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\pipenv\core.py", line 935, in do_create_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       extra=[crayons.blue(" 
{0}".format(c.err)),]
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]: Traceback (most recent call 
last):
File "c:\users\henry\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\virtualenv.py", line 2611, in <module>
main()
File "c:\users\henry\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\virtualenv.py", line 814, in main
sub_process_call = subprocess.Popen([interpreter, file] + sys.argv[1:], 
env=env)
File 
"c:\users\henry\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", 
line 775, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File 
"c:\users\henry\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", 
line 1178, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 1455] Le fichier de pagination est insuffisant pour 
terminer cette opération

Failed to create virtual environment.
```

I've tried to run pipenv shell on another previous project folder, and the problem is the same : installation i didn't ask for, and stuck during the installation. Thanks for your help !

I just wanted to run my usual virtual environment with a newer python version.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, it was apparently an issue with virtualenv.
Upgraded to 16.6.2 version.

```
pip install virtualenv==16.6.2
```